# Is there anyway to namespace resolves in ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In a ui-router state I can do something like this:

```
.state('someState', {
  url: 'somePath',
  templateUrl: 'somePath',
  controller: 'someController',
  resolve: {
    beverageBrandLookups: function(LookupFactory){
      return LookupFactory.getLookupsByType('beverageBrand')
    }
    beverageFlavorLookups: function(LookupFactory){
      return LookupFactory.getLookupsByType('beverageFlavor')
    }
  }
})
```

This works fine, but I have to inject each one into the controller separately, and I have way more then 2 lookups this is just a small example.

Is there any way to namespace within the resolve? Something like this:

```
resolve: {
  lookups: {
    brands: function(LookupFactory){
      return LookupFactory.getLookupsByType('beverageBrand')
    }
    flavors: function(LookupFactory){
      return LookupFactory.getLookupsByType('beverageFlavor')
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, but is there anything I can do that does what I'm trying to accomplish?

Basically, I don't want to inject a million different dependencies for each of the lookups in the controller. It be nice if I can bulk package resolves into a namespace so that I can just inject the one namespace.

Comment: Could use a service to combine them into one object in one resolve using `$q.all()` in the service

Comment: that sounds pretty good, didn't even think about it that way, but ui-routers resolve doesn't handle it natively then?

Comment: It does whatever you configure it to do but each property is separate. Can also avoid the injection and store each promise in that `LookupFactory` and forget about injecting the resolve and just use the stored factory promise in controller

Comment: right, each property is separate, how do you mean avoiding injection, isn't that how you resolve data before it hits the state/controller?

Comment: Idea being you want to make sure the request succeeds in the resolve but your service could store the data or promise at same time in which case all you would need to inject is the service and have it give you the new data or new promise

Comment: ah, that makes sense, thanks for the help

Comment: This basically means that you need one model/service that aggregates all these 'lookups'.

Comment: right, i've since done that, i'm guessing there isn't a way to do this with just resolves.